# How to create MTD, QTD and YTD Sum of metric

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have table with data by Region, Country, Date, month, quarter, year and sales. I am trying to design a AWS Redshift query where I could have columns for MTD (full month of sales), QTD (quarterly aggregation based on months) and YTD (yearly aggregation of months) by Region, Country, Year , Quarter and Month. Right now I am struggling with how to do running sum by quarter and by year for previous months.

Sample data:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For each year/quarter are you trying to show what the xTD values were up until that period? Seems like a strange way to present the data, usually xTD figure are shown 'as of now' and not historically as that can be very confusing.

If you are looking for regular xTD figures then use this:

```
select country,
sum(case when date >= date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) then sales else 0 end) as mtd,
sum(case when date >= date_trunc('quarter', CURRENT_DATE) then sales else 0 end) as qtd,
sum(case when date >= date_trunc('year', CURRENT_DATE) then sales else 0 end) as ytd
from data
group by country
```

Interactive example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5ffdcc3b746e801b4bd4039f8673b373).